# How to get the multiple values passing through anchor tab using JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How to get the values of multiple variables, which are passing through anchor tab using Jquery.
This is view part

```
    <a href="var1=<?php echo  $res->jid;?>&var2=<?php echo  $res->uid;?>" name="delete_user_journal">Delete</a>
```

I want to get this variable values in js page

```
  $("a[name='delete_user_journal']").each(function(index, element)
{
    var el = $(element); 
    var j_id = $(this).attr("href");
}
```

something like that, how to do this??

Comment: Why using `.each`? You have multiple element or wanna just get the variables from clicked anchor?

Comment: javascript `split()` with `&`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622600/usingjqueryhowtogetthemultiplehtmlinpval Can someone please help me solving this